# How can we set the width of the ticks?

Tags: gnuplot

In gnuplot, we can set the tick scale, but this only affects the length of the ticks.
How can we change the width of the ticks?
I don't see any option in the tags of xtics or ytics that would set the appropriate width.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check `help border`. My guess would be that the tic width can probably not set independently of the border. Well, you could play with multiple graphs with different borders and tics on top of each other. Check `help multiplot`.

**Code:**

```
### set tic width
reset session

set border lw 3
set xtics scale 4
set ytics scale 1

plot x
### end of code
```

**Result:**

[image]

Answer (score 2):

As theozh says, the tics are drawn using the 'border' line type.  If necessary I suppose you could turn off the border, set the border linetype to whatever you want the tics to be, and then use a graph-sized rectangle to replace the border.

```
set border lc "black" lw 0.25  # thin lines for the tics
set border 0                   # don't draw the normal border
set tics scale 3.0             # longer than usual tics
set obj 1 rectangle from graph 0,0 to graph 1,1
set obj 1 lc "black" lw 2.5    # heavy line for the "border"
set obj 1 fillstyle empty
set grid x y

plot sinc(x)
```

[image]